# DataTables unable to show properly in Django and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, datatables

I am currently trying to use DataTables to how the data held in my Django Model. However, I am unsure where I am going wrong with my HTML code as it is not showing the basic template table it is supposed to show. Currently, my table looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewnpX.png)

I was expecting it to look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM4MG.png)

Any form of help is appreciated. Thank you. Below are some of my code related to this problem:

results.html (the page supposed to show the table)

```html
{% extends "users/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
<!------ Side nav bar ---------->

{% block content %}
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<div class='container'>
  <table id='myTable' class='display' style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
            
    {% for result in results %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ result.website }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.anomaly_details }}</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]]
    });
} );
</script>

{% endblock script %}
```

base.html (results.html inherits this template)

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header ml-20">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OPS Web Scrape</a>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    {% block script %}{% endblock script %}
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = ResultsTable
    template_name = 'app/results.html'
    context_object_name = 'results'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global name
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['name'] = name
        return context
```

Comment: DataTables is rather picky. You have 3 `<th>` columns but 4 `<td>`s. Fix that to see if it helps. Also wrap your data `<tr>`s in a `<tbody>` tag.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. However, it seems like it is not working after these changes.

Comment: Update your question with your latest changes so that you don't get the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <table id='myTable' class='display' style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    {% for result in results %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{ result.website }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.anomaly_details }}</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ result.website }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ result.anomaly_details }}</td>
          <td class="text-center"><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block script %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]]
    });
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what changes you made in your answer and why they work

Comment: Bootstra and Jquery not loaded properly and also version of jquery is old and <th> is missing in table